# how to force the from_records to convert string to numeric?

Tags: pandas

I have list of dicts, which contain numbers as string values. Is it possible to convert the strings to numbers during process similar to from_records?

```
jdata = [{'a':1, 'b':'1'}, {'a':2, 'b':'3'}]
pd.DataFrame.from_records(jdata)
Out[129]: 
   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  3
df1.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
a    2 non-null int64
b    2 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 112.0+ bytes
```

Now I hdf1['b'] = df1['b'].apply(pd.to_numeric)

```
df1.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
a    2 non-null int64
b    2 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(2)
memory usage: 112.0 bytesave to do:
```

However, if the data are too large, the apply and the assign consume more than twice memory. Is there any way let us complete the conversion during dataframe construction?

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension:

```
jdata1 = [{k: int(v) for k, v in x.items()} for x in jdata]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(jdata1)
```

---

```
print (df.info())
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
a    2 non-null int64
b    2 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(2)
memory usage: 112.0 bytes
None
```

Comment: Well this is very primitive as loop through all dicts and items to do the conversion. Another problem is int() will not do, I'll have to implement similar function as to_numeric to convert to both int or float or even from hex or oct representation.

Comment: @Wang - In `from_records` is it not possible, unfortunately.

Comment: Is it possible to apply inplace?

Comment: @Wang - no. But solution here should be convert DataFrame or json to csv and use `pd.read_csv` - there are correctly parsed types.